# Form validation in php error in validate() function

Tags: php

In this code, I cannot match the regular expressions in validate() function help me where I was wrong

I entered data in the user input other than alphabets like (`john1246@##$##@+-`)
it returns the input value (`john1246@##$##@+-`) or $data in validate() function but not showing the error which should return `PRG_MTH_ERR`. what is the problem in my code?

validate.php

```php
function validate($data, $reg_exp = "") {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if (empty($data) == true) {
        return "EMT_FLD";
    } elseif ($data != preg_match($reg_exp,$data)) {
        return "PRG_MTH_ERR";
    } else {
        return $data;
     }
}
```

login.php

```php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
     include "./database/db.php";
     $db = new db();
     include 'validate.php';

     echo validate($_POST['user'],"/^['a-zA-z']$/");
}
```

I expected that it returns `PRG_MTH_ERR` but it returns `$data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loose comparison is your issue :

`elseif ($data != preg_match($reg_exp,$data)) {`

Because `"john1246@##$##@+-" == 0` is true.

You might compare 1 to the result of preg_match (see [the doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to learn more about preg_match)

Comment: And btw, Igor is right, you have a mistake in your regex

Answer (score 2):

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

In your code,

```
$data
```

is never returned by

```
preg_match($reg_exp,$data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$data != preg_match($reg_exp,$data)
```

to

```
1 != preg_match($reg_exp,$data)
```

and regexp to `/^[a-zA-Z]*$/`

Answer (score 2):

The preg_match() function searches string for pattern, returning true if pattern exists, and false otherwise.

So just use 
**}elseif (preg_match($reg_exp,$data)) {**
instead of 
**}elseif ($data != preg_match($reg_exp,$data)) {**

Hope it will help.